# Customize the Prompt Box of Javascript

Tags: silverlight-4.0, javascript

As the Title says, I am invoking a Prompt-box of very-flexible Javascript by the below command in my Silverlight application.
string input = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("prompt", new string[] { "YOUR QUESTION GOES HERE", "THE ANSWER INPUT GOES HERE.." }) as string;

But what i want is to customize the prompt box in terms of resizing, alignment, and Prompt-box header content. How can i pass such parameters in the above code, without breaking its core Functionality ??

Comment: If you're asking about what in JavaScript would be `window.prompt()` you _can't_ customise it. As with `.alert()` and `.confirm()` the browser sets the title and the size and position.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Plugins are available....you can use 
http://theinfiniteloopblog.com/programming/jscript/custom-javascript-alert-and-confirm-dialog-boxes/